# cryptographic exception unhandled in creating certificate

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, makecert

I am creating this simple console application that will create my own certificate. Here's my code.

```
var fi = new FileInfo("certificate.cer");
if (!fi.Exists)
{
  var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = "makecert.exe";
  startInfo.Arguments = "-sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r sha1 -n \"CN=Certificate\" -ss my -sr localmachine certificate.cer";
  Process.Start(startInfo);
}
X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("certificate.cer");
```

But why am i getting this on my last line of code?

```
CryptographicException was unhandled.
Message=The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the situation by using a batch(.bat) file, because I find it easier. And let c# run the batch file when the program starts. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for the `makecert` process to exit before using the certificate.

```
 Process
    .Start(startInfo)
    .WaitForExit();
```